# MongoDB collection.findOne() returns undefined value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
const Location = require("../models/locations");

getLocation = async(req, res) => {
   await Location.findOne(
    { name: req.query.locationName },     // req.query.locationName is "Gurgaon"
    { restaurantIds: 1 },
    (err, location) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      else {
        console.log(location);
        /*
               {
                   _id: 6004f9cff6ae9921f89f0f81,
                   restaurantIds: [ 6004fb53f6ae9921f89f0f83, 600792321b229bae25a66497 ]
               }
        */
        console.log(location._id);    // 6004f9cff6ae9921f89f0f81
        console.log(location.restaurantIds);     // undefined
        return location;
      }
    }
  );
}

module.exports = { getLocation };
```

[Screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba3zS.png)

This is how the locations collection looks like.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("6004f9cff6ae9921f89f0f81"),
  "name" : "Gurgaon",
  "restaurantIds" : [
          ObjectId("6004fb53f6ae9921f89f0f83"),
          ObjectId("600792321b229bae25a66497")
  ]
}
```

Here is the locations schema.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Locations = new Schema({}, { strict: false });

module.exports = mongoose.model("locations", Locations);
```

I don't know the reason why location.restaurantIds is returning me undefined. Please help me with this. I am new to mongodb.

Comment: could you add how data stored in mongodb document

Comment: Are you sure? you need to check again it should print when it is showing in first console.

Comment: I have checked again and again. Its printing undefined for all other keys apart from _id.

Comment: I've tested on my local and works ok. Also, if `location` output value is the same as there is into comment, then `location.restaurantIds` should works.

Comment: @J.F. It still doesn't work for me. I have added the screenshot of the output now. Are you getting the proper array output in location.restaurantIds?

Comment: @zx01 can you try adding .lean() after `findOne(...).lean()`

Comment: @turivishal lean() worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: @zx01 good one more thing can you post your schema. have you specified this field in your schema?

Comment: @turivishal I have posted the schema. I didn't specify the field. Is that the reason why it was not working before?

Comment: yes that was the reason, i have added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be some reasons might be you have not specified this field in your mongoose schema, try adding field in your schema and you are able to access this field in your query.

---

Second option if you don't want to specify that field in schema then try [lean()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html),

By default, Mongoose queries return an instance of the Mongoose Document class. Enabling the lean option tells Mongoose to skip instantiating a full Mongoose document and just give you the POJO.

```
await Location.findOne(.. your query).lean();
```

Answer (score 0):

restaurantIds is a nested object , you must populate it :

```
const Location = require("../models/locations");

getLocation = async(req, res) => {
   await Location.findOne(
    { name: req.query.locationName },   
    { restaurantIds: 1 })
    .populate('restaurantIds').then(location => {
        console.log(location);
        console.log(location._id);   
        console.log(location.restaurantIds);
        return location;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            throw err;
        })
  );
}

module.exports = { getLocation };
```

Answer (score -1):

It's look like your `restaurantIds` is an array, so when you print it, you must use as array. Start by change:

```
console.log(location.restaurantIds);
```

to:

```
console.log(location.restaurantIds[0]);
```

In this example, you will be printing the first object in the array, and use it in your code as array, it will be OK.

**Edit:**
After added the `restaurantIds`, and now we know it's array of ObjectID, and this kind of array cannot be printed.

Comment: When I change into that, I get this - TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

Comment: That was before you added 'ObjectId'.